# Vimeo API: Can't upload video - "No user credentials were provided." (8003)

Tags: reactjs, video, upload, axios, vimeo

I'm trying to upload a video from my ReactJS application to Vimeo but I'm getting a "No user credentials were provided." error (8003).

I followed this guide from the Vimeo API: https://developer.vimeo.com/api/upload/videos#form-approach

My code (for the first step of uploading a video):

```
const accessToken = "74a218e620507395c78219ab9421639c";

const size = form.file.size; // size of video in bytes

axios
  .post("https://api.vimeo.com/me/videos", {
    headers: {
      Accept: "application/vnd.vimeo.*+json;version=3.4",
      "Content-Type": "application/json",
      Authorization: "bearer " + accessToken,
    },
    upload: {
      approach: "post",
      size: size,
      redirect_url: "http://localhost:8083/success1",
    },
  })
  .then((response) => {
    console.log(response.data);
  })
  .catch((error) => {
    console.log(error);
    console.log(error.response);
  });
```

The response:

[image]

As you see I do have upload access.

[image]

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

If the access token you shared is what you're actually using, the token only has `public` scope, which I verified by making a request with that token to `/oauth/verify` endpoint ([docs here](https://developer.vimeo.com/api/reference/authentication-extras#verify_token)).

If the token you put in your post was a "dummy" token for the purposes of posting here, then make a request to that endpoint with your real token and take a look at the response -- if it's an [unauthenticated (client_credentials) token](https://developer.vimeo.com/api/authentication#table-2), or if it's an authenticated token that doesn't have the scopes `public private edit upload` [it cannot be used for upload](https://developer.vimeo.com/api/upload/videos#before-you-begin).

Comment: It is indeed a real token, I didn't know I needed another scope. Either way I'm getting the same problem with this token: 74a218e620507395c78219ab9421639c this one has all the permissions.